# Ebay: What is the best API to return sold items count

Tags: api, ebay-api, naivebayes, ebay-sdk

I am trying to play with EBay API but their documentation is really of not much help. What I am trying to do is use an API that searches results between a given start date and end date. Then based on this date frame, the API would return how many items were sold per each returned item - I am thinking of quantity of each sold item.

Any guidance would be appreciated...

Answer (score 3):

Try **Shopping** API and it's method **GetMultipleItems()**.

```
r={
   'ItemID': itemId_list, #list of items ID, max 20 items per query
   'IncludeSelector': 'Details'
}
response = api.execute('GetMultipleItems', r)
```

You will be able to get from **response.reply.Item** parameters like:

```
item.ItemID #item id
item.Quantity #stock
item.QuantitySold #how many sold
item.HitCount #number of clicks on the item
```

Here is my code with all the details: https://github.com/Brat-Pit/eBay/blob/master/eBay_api.py

Comment: Does this API has a limit? because it looks like I would have to do a search request for and whatever items I get, I would have to iterate through them and using them in GetMultipleItems() to get 20 results each time...

Comment: Yeah. Daily limit is 5k queries, so the maximum number of items to be analysed would be around 5k*20=100k per day..